# C++ : Strange metafunction call

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, pow

I have a strange metafunction behavior in my C++ code and I want to understand why.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

inline double f(double x, double y)
{
    std::cout<<"Marker"<<std::endl;
    return sqrt(x*y);
}

template <int N, class T> inline T metaPow(T x)
{
    return ((N > 0) ? (x*metaPow<((N > 0) ? (N-1) : (0))>(x)) : (1.));
}


int main()
{
    double x;
    double y;
    std::cin>>x;
    std::cin>>y;
    std::cout<<metaPow<5>(f(x, y))<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I expected that the line `metaPow<5>(f(x, y))` was equivalent to `f(x, y)*f(x, y)*f(x, y)*f(x, y)*f(x, y)*1.`. But if it was, it would print me five times the "`Marker`" line in the `f` function.

The strange thing is that I have the good result at the end (for example `181.019` for `x = 2` and `y = 4`) but I have only 1 "`Marker`" displayed. How is it possible ? And consequently is it a good option to use that function for compile-time optimization instead of the standard pow() ?

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that `f(x,y)` is being evaluated before being passed in to your metaPow function.  So the x argument to metaPow is just the value sqrt*(8).  metaPow is never calling f(x,y).  Hence, f(x,y) is only called once - when you initially call metaPow in your main function.

Answer (score 2):

I think:

> metaPow<5>(f(x, y))

equals to

> double z = f(x, y); metaPow<5>(z);